# Offcanvas not working in foundation 6.2

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

WHy is my offcanvas not working I simply copied zurb's example and added the following javascripts (seen below) just before the closing body tag, but nothing happens when I click the menu icon. Does anybody know what is wrong? Am I including the correct js files?

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bower_components it should work.